# how to get dataset of 10.000 static html pages from Wiki

Tags: dataset, wikipedia

I am working on a classification algorithm. In order to do that I need a dataset that contains about 10,000 static HTML pages from wikimedia. Something like
page-title-1.html .... page-title-10000.html

I tried Google and I find out that my best solution was downloading it from http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/static_html_dumps/2008-06/en/.

However, I do not know how to use it in order to get what I want.

There are some files as following

```
html.lst    2008-Jun-19 17:25:05    692.2M  application/octet-stream
images.lst  2008-Jun-19 18:02:09    307.4M  application/octet-stream
skins.lst   2008-Jun-19 17:25:06    6.0K    application/octet-stream
wikipedia-en-html.tar.7z    2008-Jun-21 16:44:22    14.3G   application/x-7z-compressed
```

I want to know how to do with *.lst files and what is in `wikipedia-en-html.tar.7z`

Comment: Download 7zip to uncompress the archive. http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: Yeah, thank for your advice, i will try it, but wikipedia-en-html.tar.7z is about 14G, it will take some time to get the file, i just want to be sure if i can get html files or or other *.lst files. I do not know how to do with *.lst files.

Comment: The `*.lst` files contain lists of files, not actual content.  I doubt the main archive contains HTML - it's more likely to be wiki markup.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read [the section "Static HTML tree dumps for mirroring or CD distribution" of *Database download* on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download#Static_HTML_tree_dumps_for_mirroring_or_CD_distribution) (and in fact that whole page, which points you to 7zip for unpacking the main archive).